# Balls into boxes with double restriction.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that you have $N$ boxes in which one can distribute $b_T\leq N$ indistinguishable balls such that there is at most one ball in every box.

Now from the $N$ boxes contruct $N_d$ boxes with $\nu=N/N_d$ boxes each. The question is to find the probability that, choosing $n$ boxes from the $N_d$, each box contains at least one ball.

Attempt:

The possible ways in which the $n$ boxes can get at least one ball is

$$
X=\binom{N_d}{n}\times \nu^n\times\binom{(v-1)n}{b_T - n},
$$

where each of the terms are:

1. $\binom{N_d}{n}$ is the number of ways in which we can choose the $n$ non-empty boxes
2. $\nu^n$ is the number of ways in which we can accomodate at least one ball in each box (Remember that from the $n$-boxes, each box has another $\nu$ boxes inside).
3. $\binom{(v-1)n}{b_T - n}$ is the number of ways in which we can distribute the rest of the balls $b_T-n$ in the remaining allowed $(\nu-1)n$ sites.

The probability we are looking for is

$$
\frac{X}{\binom{N}{b_T}}.
$$

EDIT: I just found an overcounting regarding the last two factors, but I don't know how to get rid off.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have a correct formula for the probability in the form of a sum involving binomial coefficients that I don't recognize.  It may be possible to simplify it, but I can't see how.

First, let's reformulate the problem a little.  Consider all the $N-$bit strings with exactly $b_T$ one bits.  There are $\binom{N}{b_T}$ of these.  We want to know in how many of these strings is each of the first $n$ non-overlapping $\nu-$ bit substrings not identically zero.  (Clearly, there is no loss of generality in assuming that the $n$ "boxes" chosen are the first ones.)

It seems a lot easier to calculate the probability that at least one of the substrings is $0.$  There are $n$ ways to choose a substring, and then $\binom{N-\nu}{b_t}$ ways to distribute the one-bits to the rest of the string.  However, we have to to subtract the strings with $2$ zero substrings, or $\binom{n}{2}\binom{N-2\nu}{b_t}$.  Proceeding by inclusion-exclusion gives$$
\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{N-k\nu}{b_T}}{\binom{N}{b_T}}$$

Comment: I think there is something amiss, because if the number of boxes $n$ is one, then the probability should be equal to 1, i.e. the numerator must equal $\binom{N}{b_T}$

Comment: @user2820579 I don't see that at all.  If $n=1$ we are choosing just one of the group of $\nu$ boxes aren't we?  Why does there have to be a ball in one of those $\nu$ boxes?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. We have $N$ boxes and from them the aim is to divide these into $n$ sub-boxes with the same number of boxes each. That is, if $n=1$, then we have one big box with $N$ (even) boxes in it. If $n=2$, then we have 2 sub-boxes, each one with $N/2$ boxes in it; etc.

Comment: Then what is $N_d?$  The question says to build $N_d$ sub-boxes and choose $n$ of the sub-boxes.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In my previous comment I meant $N_d$ instead of $n$.

Comment: @user2820579 $N_d=1\implies\nu=N,$ so for $n=1,$ the formula does give $1.$  (It also gives $1$ for $n=0,$ which is vacuously correct.)   I guess I should have stated that the formula is correct only for $0\le n\le N_d.$